# Facebook sdk 3.1 on iOS 5?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

my app has facebook sdk 3.1 integrated. It works well with iOS 6 but crashes on iOS 5. I get the following error in the console.

```
2012-11-08 12:57:04.529 FMB[3446:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBSession handleDidBecomeActive]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6977300'
*** First throw call stack: (0x1b54052 0x129bd0a 0x1b55ced 0x1abaf00 0x1abace2 0x695f 0x40922c 0x40aa66 0x419743 0x41a1f8 0x40daa9 0x22adfa9 0x1b281c5 0x1a8d022 0x1a8b90a 0x1a8adb4 0x1a8accb 0x40a2a7 0x40ba9b 0x2ed2 0x2e05) terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: I'm having nearly the exact same issue - mine happens on both versions of iOS though.  Had you found a solution?

Comment: Just found my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847953/fbrequest-requestforme-unrecognized-selector