# Facebook IOS SDK error: +[FBSession activeSession]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xbfc94'

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to allow people to login using Facebook.

I get the following error:

```
* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[FBSession activeSession]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xbfc94'
```

not sure why.

I followed the instructions here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/

to integrate the Facebook SDK into my app.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Exactly the same issue here - any solution?

Comment: Just found my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847953/fbrequest-requestforme-unrecognized-selector